# Analysis 1 (Terence Tao): Cauchy Sequence Lemma involving Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

[image]

I put an orange arrow next to where I'm having trouble comprehending. I understand everything except the last sentence of the paragraph in question.

How is it that we can conclude from the triangle inequality that $\left\lvert b_n\right\rvert$ $\geq$ $\frac\epsilon 2$ for all n $\geq$ N?

Thanks all!

Comment: He's asking you, not me :) Have you tried to use the triangle inequality, together with that $|b_{n_0} - b_n| \le \epsilon /2$?

Comment: @Calvin Khor Tao only gives one illustration of the triangle inequality ($\left\lvert b_{n_0} + b_n\right\rvert$ $\leq$ $\left\lvert b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ + $\left\lvert b_n\right\rvert$). So using that triangle inequality in this case: $\left\lvert b_{n_0} - b_n\right\rvert$ $\leq$ $\left\lvert b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ + $\left\lvert -b_n\right\rvert$ = $\left\lvert b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ + $\left\lvert  b_n\right\rvert$ $\leq$   $\frac\epsilon 2$. But I'm a bit stuck here.

Comment: No you don't wanna do that. You want to somehow end up with $|b_n|>\epsilon/2$ so you need to see $>\epsilon/2$. One way to find this is by trying to get $>\epsilon - \epsilon/2$, and you need the minus sign because you were given something $<\epsilon/2$ and the $<$ is the wrong way....

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rearrange the terms of triangle inequality.

$$|b_{n0}| \le |b_{n_0} - b_n| + |b_n|$$

Thus

$$|b_n| \ge |b_{n0}| - |b_{n_0} - b_n|$$

Comment: Ok. trying to follow: $\left\lvert b_{n_0} - b_n\right\rvert$ $\leq$ $\left\lvert b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ + $\left\lvert -b_n\right\rvert$ = $\left\lvert b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ + $\left\lvert  b_n\right\rvert$. Subtracting $\left\lvert b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ from both sides gives $\left\lvert b_{n_0} - b_n\right\rvert$ - $\left\lvert  b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ $\leq$ $\left\lvert b_{n}\right\rvert$. How are you getting (-$\left\lvert b_{n_0} - b_n\right\rvert$) + $\left\lvert  b_{n_0}\right\rvert$ $\leq$ $\left\lvert b_{n}\right\rvert$?

Comment: Actually both are true. You can in fact show $|b_n| \geq ||b_{n_0}| - |b_{n_0} - b_n||$.